# Azure Backup Agent Install Generating Error

Tags: azure, backup, agent, passphrase

I am encountering this error, "100024 The encryption passphrase provided does not match with passphrase associated with the following server: %ServerName Please update the server settings with the current passphrase for data encryption."  I used the passphrase generator in the install wizard and I used the same from the Azure Backup GUI - e.g. "Register".  Created phase phrases many times.  Uploaded a self-signed certificate to Azure Backup.  I installed, uninstalled and installed again MARSAgentInstaller.exe several times.  The agent installer is installed on a domain controller.  The server has Windows Server 2012 R2 Essentials running.  The "Download Agent for Windows Server Essentials" (OnlineBackupAddin) was run.  Much googling was done.  Every combination imaginable was tried.  The error remains and backups cannot be performed.  Any solutions, suggestions or hints will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: When did youbdownload the credential file? Take notice that this only is valid for 24hours

Comment: Yes.  I did register the server with a current credential file.  Credentials files are good for 2 days.

Comment: Ahhh... finally got it to work.  On the Microsoft Azure portal, under azure backups, there is the primary menu bar (dashboard|registered items|protected items...).  Under register items, my server was listed as a Windows Server.  To make sure everything was clean, I removed that registered server and started over.  I started the Microsoft Azure Backup app from the W2012R2E server.  I went to the menu bar on the right and clicked Register Server.  I browsed to a fresh credential file.  Then I generated a passphrase with the GUI and saved it.  Then it succeeded.